# Moment's fromNow returning strange result

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using `fromNow` in Moment and I seem to be getting some odd results.

```
var moment = require('moment');

var months = {
    Jan: '1', Feb: '2', Mar: '3', Apr: '4',
    May: '5', Jun: '6', Jul: '7', Aug: '8',
    Sep: '9', Oct: '10', Nov: '11', Dec: '12' }

var input = "3 Aug 2015, 12:30".replace(/,/g, "").split(' ')
var time = input.pop().split(':')
var date = input.reverse()
var t = date.concat(time);

t[1] = months[t[1]];
t = moment(t);

console.log(t.fromNow());
```

This is printing out "in a month".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the array you're feeding into `moment` (i.e. `["2015", "Aug", "3", "12", "30"]`) is not a valid date. If you print out `t.toDate()` after assigning it `moment(t)` it states "Invalid Date".

Why not simply doing it like this and let moment parse your date properly:

```
var m = moment("3 Aug 2015, 12:30", "DD MMM YYYY, HH:mm");
console.log(m.fromNow());

> in 5 hours
```

Comment: He does not use `["2015", "Aug", "3", "12", "30"]`, but `["2015", "8", "3", "12", "30"]` (notice `t[1] = months[t[1]]`). Unfortunately, `8` is September according to JavaScript, as JS counts months from zero. Your point about letting moment parse it still remains.

Comment: Indexes seem to be okay, I don't see any misspelled month names. What do you mean? But `months` object *values* being wrong is the only thing he messed up (besides overcomplicating in the first place)

Comment: His indexes are 1-based, instead of 0-based for the months.

Comment: His indexes are `"Jan"`, `"Feb"` etc. His *values* are month numbers, which are offset by one as I said in the first comment. And if you meant "he got the values wrong, too", then I don't understand what "too" means, since that is his only mistake - that was preventing me from understanding what you meant.

Comment: My bad then, but merely semantics, we're saying the same thing.

Comment: It seems we are. But for a programmer, semantics is important, given that one *character* more or less can make a huge difference.